# Any way to recover model passed to POST action when inside OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, model, action-filter, onexception

Situation is this:

I can't find a way of getting the `viewModel` that was passed to the POST action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(SomeCoolModel viewModel)
{
    // Some Exception happens here during the action execution...
}
```

Inside the overridable `OnException` for the controller:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    ...

    filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
    {
        ViewName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(),
        TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData,
        ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData
    };
}
```

When debugging the code `filterContext.Controller.ViewData` is `null` since the exception occurred while the code was executing and no view was returned.

Anyways I see that `filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState` is filled and has all the values that I need but I don't have the full `ViewData => viewModel` object available. :(

I want to return the same `View` with the posted `data/ViewModel` back to the user in a central point. Hope you get my drift.

Is there any other path I can follow to achieve the objective?

Comment: Not entirely sure I _get your drift_, but in the `OnException()` method you could try something like `MyModel m = new MyModel(); TryUpdateModel<MyModel>(m);` to give you the model, but of course you would need to know the type so not very flexible

Comment: @StephenMuecke awesome start... It filled the model with the `ModelState` values but the bad part is what you mentioned: it's not dynamic\flexible. I'm looking to add some bit of `dynamic` to this. :) If I get this to work it will allow me to avoid writing a lot of repetitive code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a custom model binder that inherits from [DefaultModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder(v=vs.118).aspx) and assign the model to `TempData`:

```
public class MyCustomerBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        base.OnModelUpdated(controllerContext, bindingContext);

        controllerContext.Controller.TempData["model"] = bindingContext.Model;
    }
}
```

and register it in `Global.asax`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new MyCustomerBinder();
```

then access it:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    var model = filterContext.Controller.TempData["model"];

    ...
}
```

Comment: WAO! Worked beautifully... `ASP.NET MVC` is so good that you can plug into it in so many places: the thing is to know where to plug.
God bless your life. :-)

Comment: Two years later and still working as a charm! Thanks.